# Xamarin Forms Collection View Extra Padding

Tags: xamarin.forms

I"m trying out the Xamarin Forms Collection View. It appears to have some extra padding around each item in the list. I can't see how to remove it.

Here is a picture of my view. The view has an aqua background. The 2 column grid in the template has labels set to red.

[image]

And here is the XAML/C#

```
<CollectionView 
    x:Name="BodyView"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    BackgroundColor="Aqua"
    Grid.Row="2" />

BodyView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    var converter = (IValueConverter) Application.Current.Resources["GridCellConverter"];

    Grid grid = new Grid( );
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });

    foreach (var col in _gridColumns)
    {
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

        var content = new Label();
        content.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["GridCellLabel"];
        content.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        Binding binding = new Binding("CellData", BindingMode.OneWay, converter, col.PageFieldId);
        content.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, binding);
        grid.Children.Add(content, grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1, 0);
    }

    return grid;
});
```

I zeroed everything I could find to zero.

I tried setting a negative margin on the grid but it won't move left.

Is there any way to remove the padding?

Comment: How did you set the `Style` for the **GridCellLabel**? Did you set the **Margin** for it? You could specify a value for the **BackgroundColor** property of the grid in 'BodyView.ItemTemplate' to check if the grid fills the collectionView's width.

Comment: GridCellLabel style is just size and text color. I tried setting the grid background color. I set all the things background colors! The padding is definitely from the collection view. I'm pretty sure it is hard coded but was hoping someone might have an idea.

Comment: Could you share a basic demo link? It'll help to reproduce the issue to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the Grid's Row and Column Spacing!

```
    Grid grid = new Grid( ){ ColumnSpacing= "0", RowSpacing="0" };
```

Also, this needs to be removed:

```
    grid.Margin = new Thickness(-20, 0, 0, 0);
```

A quick question though are you using it in UWP?

Also since you are using `CollectionView` why not use a single item in DataTemplate that goes into a `GridItemsLayout`?

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid

Comment: I was pretty sure it was not grid column or row spacing as it is the space on the left and right of the rows I want to remove, but I tried it anyway and it didn't change anything. The negative margin was there to try and move the grid to the left but that didn't work. I'll remove it from the example to remove confusion.

Comment: Did you try GridsItemLayout?

Comment: Oh yeah also by any chance do you have a Frame in your layout because a Frame has a default 20 padding check for that as well

Comment: There is a Frame around the whole thing but I set the Padding to 5. I'm pretty sure the Padding is from the CollectionView. I'm not using Grid Layout as that is for displaying multiple items on one row, wheras I want one item on each row. My internal layout is fine - I just need to reduce the padding